# which of the following statement is true/false?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Given  $f : [ \frac{1}{2}, 2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ , a  strictly  increasing  function  , we  put  $g(x) = f(x)  + f(1/x)  , x \in  [1,2]$.
Consider  a  partition  $P$ of $[1, 2] $ and let $U(P,g)$ and $L(P, g)$ denotes  the upper sum Reimann sum and  lower  Reimann sum of $g$ . Then
which of the following statement is true/false ?

$1.$ For  a  suitable  $f$ we  can have  $U(P, g) = L (P, g)$

$2$. for a suitable  $f$ we can have  $U(P, g) \neq L (P,g)$

$3$.$U(P,g) \ge L (P,g)$ for  all  choices of  $f$

$4$. $U(P,g) < L(P,g) $for all  choices  of $f$

any hints/solution

Comment: Isn't 3 corect for any $g$ by the definitions of $L$, $U$?

Comment: @denklo i thinks  option 3  is also  correct  take $f(x) = x - 1/2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. This is correct. Take $f(x)=\log(x)$. Then $g(x)=0$.
2. This is correct too. Take $f(x)=x$, for instance.
3. This is true, of course.
4. This inequality *never* occurs.